# How to Read current VM names and increment new name if they exist

Tags: powershell, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I am totally at a loss here. I have searched for hours and can't find what I am looking for. This is my last hope O B 1.

I need a powershell command that will check if a hyper-v vm name exists and increment the name up by one if it does. The name would be like 'ABC-DEFG123'

Also, open to suggestions if there is a better way to get it done

Can't find any similar examples on the net.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for how to research a solution here, I would suggest digging into the PowerShell Hyper-V module and on manipulating strings using Regex. Depending on your comfort level with PowerShell, you may want to work through some tutorials there too (some references provided at the end).

One way to handle this is to break it down into multiple steps.

1. Retrieve all the VMs from Hyper-V using the PowerShell module. The cmdlet is: `Get-VM`
2. Grab the name and break it apart into alpha and numeric portions (regex is easiest). Based on your example, you might use a regex filter like `^(.*?)(\d+)$`
3. Increment the integer and rebuild a new name.

A basic snippet might look like this:

```
$regex = '^(.*?)(\d+)$'; # This created two groups. One with the text and one with any trailing numbers
$name = 'ABC-DEF123';
$vm = Get-VM -Name $name;
if ($vm.Name -match $regex) {
  $prefix = $matches[1]; # This is the text portion of the string
  $idx = $matches[2] -as [int]; # This is the current index
  $newName = "$($prefix)$($idx + 1)"; # This will build a new name with an incremented index
}
Write-Host "Old Name: $($vm.Name)";
Write-Host "New Name: $newName";
```

A few references to help your research:

- [Working with HyperV](https://adamtheautomator.com/hyper-v-powershell/) - From AdamTheAutomator
- [Regexr](https://regexr.com/) - Great regex development/testing environment
- Something like [RegexLearn](https://regexlearn.com/) may help as well.
- [Microsoft Regex Information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-7.3&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-7)
- [Microsoft PowerShell Training](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/paths/powershell/)
- [Manage Windows Server Settings Using PowerShell Cmdlets | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/manage-windows-server-settings-use-powershell-cmdlets/)